# Magento 2.2.6 Web Setup Wizard missing

Tags: magento2.2.6

I am running Magento 2.2.6 and just tried to purchase and install an extension from the Magento market place but when I goto the admin I don't have the web setup wizard to install extensions.

Please can someone advise how to install extensions purchased on Magento market place.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Send screenshot or steps that you following for installing your purchased extension.

Comment: maybe you just unzip it, and use cli 'bin/magento'